# The best type of silicone to use on a drop-in kitchen sink with raised sides on stone top

Tags: adhesive

I have a black stone surface and a drop-in double sink with raised sides in my kitchen. I need to secure the sink from shifting. what is the best type of silicone sealant to use?

Comment: There really is only one kind of silicone (though silicone can be an ingredient in other caulk products). Are you asking what type of caulk to use? Please edit your question and title to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

if its a drop in sink, you don't use silicone - you use plumbers putty.  the clamp bolts hold it in place, and the putty acts as the seal.  if you silicone it and ever have to replace it, you will never get it out without breaking the granite.

if you are 100% dedicated to doing it wrong and insist on using silicone, use ge silicone I, but not silicone II (its for outside and has uv protectant in it, and it can discolour some types of granite)